# How to get Glass serial number programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-glass

How can I get the 14 character alphanumeric(like LGGXXXXXXXXXXX) serial number of Google Glass programmatically?

Comment: What a reason for downvote ? Seems legal question to me.

Comment: Actually I need the id for making a unique communication channel between glass and server.

Comment: How about IMEI ? Its unique.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id

Comment: I have used.... TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();...but it gives null value.

Comment: Did you try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/3330969) ?

Comment: Thanks @Morrison Chang. But I am looking for serial number like LGGXXXXXXXXXXX, which is written on the box of glass or this unique number would be visible after Bluetooth connectivity with Android phone/tab via MyGlass app.

Comment: Yes @Kedarnath it gives Android OS unique id, I believe its not available for end user, only developer can access it via coding. I need that serial number because that is known by both end user as well as developer.

Comment: Did you check the "about phone"->"Status" option in real device ?

Comment: Thanks @Kedarnath but I am looking for Glass serial number not Android phone device id.

Comment: Ha ha ha... I just forgot that it is google-glass not a phone :P

Comment: @Kedarnath Google Glass does not have IMEI since it also does not have  GSM hardware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you can get the Android Serial easily by retrieving the value android.os.Build.SERIAL

For example:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Serial: "+android.os.Build.SERIAL);
```

For the Device Serial it is more complex, but I was able to retrieve it too using reflection:

```
public static String getGlassSerial(Context context) {
  String prop="ro.serialno.glass";
  String result=null;
  try{
    Class SystemProperties =
      context.getClassLoader().loadClass("android.os.SystemProperties");

    Class[] paramtypes=new Class[1];
    paramtypes[0]=String.class;
    Object[] paramvalues=new Object[1];
    paramvalues[0]=new String(prop);      
    Method get=SystemProperties.getMethod("get", paramtypes);

    result=(String) get.invoke(SystemProperties, paramvalues);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    result=null;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives Android OS serial number but I am looking for Glass hardware ID that is visible in MyGlass Android application used to setup Glass.

Comment: after a bit of hacking I was able to find a way to retrieve the device serial too. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yeah I am able to get device serial. This code is working fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know if it still works on google glass with latest XE release?